# Не могу унаследоваться от Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android

Пытаюсь создать стиль с таким содержимым (скопировано с гугла):

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

Выдавало ошибку, что не находит тему `Theme.AppCompat.Light`. Для этого я добавил библиотеку `android-support-v7-appcompat` в проекты и экспортировал ее в проект. Но теперь в проекте библиотеки ошибка:

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.

В самом проекте программы появился восклицательный знак и все буквы R подчеркнуты красным.

Что тут не так, что я не так делаю и как это исправить?

**Фото проектов для Юрия:**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В Eclipse работаете?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, а это имеет значение?

Comment: Да, см. ответ. Это косяк Eclipse/

Comment: Попробуйте также своему проекту по аналогии с инструкцией в ответе проставить наксимальное апи и проерьте, что библиотека подключена к вашему проекту.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я установил Android Studio. Чтобы не было тараканов (как всегда), руками перенесу проект, а потом заново буду пытаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается так:

1. Правой кнопкой на проект библиотеки-Свойства
2. Вкладка Android
3. В таблице Project Build Target выбрать максимальную версию API.

Comment: Ошибка в проекте библиотеки исчезла, но в проекте приложения все R подчеркнуты красной линией.

Comment: Возможно, теперь R класс надо заново импортировать в классы.

Comment: Хм... А как? :)

Comment: Ну... Так же как обычно... `import имяпакета.R;`

Comment: Какого пакета? Я раньше никогда не импортировал R вручную...

Comment: Пакет приложения вашего... Для простого импорта курсор на строку с ошибкой установите и нажмите `ctrl+1`

Comment: Импортировало ``import android.R;``, но теперь в строке ``setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);`` подсвечивается не R, a ``main_activity``... А ошибки вот такие: - main_activity cannot be resolved or is 
  not a field
 - R cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Вам надо импортировать R своего проекта. Т.е. что-то типа su.cccp.leninrules.R. Также попробуйте сделать `clean` проекту. Как - не помню, но гугл всё знает.

Comment: просто перебилдите теперь проект

Comment: насколько я помню в эклипсе должно быть что-то в роде file- R generate, функция которая заново генерит R.java. А вообще переходите на AS

Comment: Юрий, сделал ``clean`` и импортировал ``import com.example.dictionarydemo_2.R;``, ошибка — The import com.example.dictionarydemo_2.R cannot be resolved и все R подчеркнуты.

Comment: @АндройдАндройд, не нашел. А для AS у меня компьютер слабоват, не вытянет.

Comment: Проверьте на ошибки все xml файлы в вашем проекте. R не генерируется обычно из-за этого.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, все в порядке, ошибки не высвечиваются.

Comment: А в проекте библиотеки которую подключали? Таки должны быть ошибки.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, и там все тихо! Ну... По крайней мере, ошибки не высвечиваются.

Comment: Ни в разметке, ни в стилях или других values?.. 0_o

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ни в разметке, ни в стилях или других values...

Comment: Ну хз... Всё мною и остальными написанное должно работать, ибо проверялось не раз. Вы что-то пропустили. Попробуйте пройти весь путь с начала и до конца.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, слишком непонятно для меня. 100% попаду на ту же ошибку. Попробую реализовать все это через ``AlertDialog``. Он не упаковывает ``layout`` в ``View`` и, надеюсь, умеет убирать ``toolbar``.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а нет... Там нельзя свою разметку установить... Потопал я Android Studio ставить. Эх... Крепись мой старый пентиум!

Comment: мне кажется вам надо обновить железо, для современной разработки это просто необходимое требование.